# MS Access 2003 - Auto fill form-field based on previous form field.

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I am currently attempting to design a database that requires a number of users inputting data via forms.

one of these tables is  a 'user' table. Amongst the information in the table is 
userid (int),
username (text),
first name (text),
last name (text)

In the even that I'm filling out a form and supply the the username in the username field is it possible  if the username already exists to pull the first name and last name from the user table and auto-populate those form fields? If so can you point me in the right direction please?

Directly via access functionality or via vba? If not possible in 2003 is this possible in 2007?

Comment: Does the username have unique index? Are you creating new table entries from this form?

Comment: the user id is the primary index and the username is always unique

I'm trying to setup 1 form to update four tables, one of those table entries that are being updated is the user table described enough (assuming the username isn't already found within it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar form  and i use to make these field as Comboboxes. 
Then set the property row source as a query.

Set the criteria Where like this

```
WHERE ((([Users].Username) Like '*' & [Forms]![YourForm]![Username] & '*'));
```

This will allow the user to choose the name as fast as possible

But it will not fill it automatically because my users can have the same username as others.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now for the auto fill (yes i did find one example), This will fill the username after you filled the userid (Both should be comboboxes in this case called Usernamecombo and useridcombo)
First make the query with a SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT [User].username FROM User WHERE ((([User].userid) Like '*' & [Forms]![Yourform]![useridcombo] & '*'));
```

Lets call this query "qry_username".
Then go to designview of the form and to the properties of the useridcombo, in the event/afterupdate property you make a event procedure (VBA) :

```
Private Sub useridcombo_AfterUpdate()

[Forms]![yourform]![Usernamecombo].Value = DFirst("username", "qry_username")
Forms("yourform").[Usernamecombo].Requery 'this last line is optional

End sub
```

Other fields can be added to the VBA pretty simply(dont forget the query)

```
Private Sub useridcombo_AfterUpdate()

[Forms]![yourform]![Usernamecombo].Value = DFirst("username", "qry_username")
[Forms]![yourform]![Firstnamecombo].Value = DFirst("Firstname", "qry_username")
[Forms]![yourform]![Lastnamecombo].Value = DFirst("Lastname", "qry_username")
Forms("yourform").[Usernamecombo].Requery 'this last line is optional

End sub
```

Comment: So, in this example I provide the username and it returns the userid? Is that correct? 

Can this be modified then considering I have three entry forms, 

usersername, firstname, lastname to auto populate the latter two when the first one is filled? No forms are actually being created in this place, I'd just add the userid to another table in this case - its more of a visual confirmation.

Comment: This was just for auto populating the form based on the userID. In this case you select a UserID in the combobox. The username is then returned in his own combobox. If you add the firstname and lastname to the query and to the VBA they will be filled in the same way.